# How to remove footer powered by in OpensourcePOS?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wonder how can I remove footer option saying "Your are using Open Source POS Version blah blah". I've already tried to edit files but after saving and restarting server UI get blocked. that means we can't change in footer. is there anyway to edit this option without blocking UI?

Comment: Are you using codeigniter frame work you  have put codeigniter tag but OpensourcePOS

Answer (score 3):

Please Just add this in application/views/partial/header.php

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.blockUI').remove();
        });
      </script>
```

Problem Solved :)

Answer (score 1):

> The footer signature "You are using Open Source Point Of Sale" with version, hash and link to the original distribution of the code MUST BE RETAINED, MUST BE VISIBLE IN EVERY PAGE and CANNOT BE MODIFIED.

Better leave it as it is. Someone went through a lot of trouble making it work, and lets you use it for free. Donate instead of altering stuff you are not supposed to touch.

Answer (score 0):

Its against the license terms to remove the footer. It is always professional and to credit someone's work and effort. Anyway you just need to open application/views/partial/footer.php and remove the following code:

```
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="jumbotron push-spaces">
            <strong><?php echo $this->lang->line('common_you_are_using_ospos'); ?>
            <?php echo $this->config->item('application_version'); ?> - <?php echo substr($this->config->item('commit_sha1'), 0, 6); ?></strong>.
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('common_please_visit_my'); ?>
            <a href="https://github.com/jekkos/opensourcepos" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->lang->line('common_website'); ?></a>
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('common_learn_about_project'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```